# Editing percentage value in Userform TextBox

Tags: excel, textbox, userform, vba

I am attempting to create a textbox which allows users to input a percentage between 1-5% in my Excel-VBA Userform. I have created the textbox and added code to restrict the formatting to always show as a percentage. My problem is that when I attempt to edit the default percentage in the textbox by pressing backspace the decimal moves two spaces to the right instead of deleting any present values. Below is a copy of my code. Please note that the Textbox is not locked.

```
Private Sub PV_change()

PV.Text = Format(PV.Value, "Percent")

End Sub
```

Comment: Why is it necessary to have the textbox *display* the %? It would seem preferable to simply handle the user input in the dependent procedures/functions, and do a conversion there e.g., `CDbl(PV.Value)/100)`

Comment: @DavidZemens I suppose it is not necessary but it makes the userform more intuitive to the user if they are clearly aware the value is a %.

Comment: It will make it harder for the user to enter though, as they will have to enter `.05` in order to get `5%` displayed.

Comment: It won't work as posted.  Try typing 0.05 - I get `0.00%.05` It's because after the first key stroke the text box contains `0.00%` then after the second key it's `0.00%.` which is no longer interperatable as a number and `Format` fails and returns the original string.  Better to put a string next to the text box to indicate %, and handle the conversion elsewhere

Comment: @chrisneilsen I wish I could up-vote your comment by about +100

Comment: Just put a *label* next to the textbox, and have the label's caption as "%", otherwise, you're going to have a helluva time trying to intercept keystrokes (backspaces, etc.) and interpret what the user is actually doing. There's a reason most web forms normalize data like SSN, Phone Numbers, etc., and don't let you input the hyphen/dash, and most survey forms ask you to fill in a percent as an integer value, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could do your code in the `PV_Exit` procedure rather than the `_Change` procedure, but I still think you're asking for trouble this way :)

```
Private Sub PV_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    PV.Value = Format(PV.Value, "Percent")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the objections made previously, but to show a simple solution without error trapping try this:

```
Private Sub tbPV_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
Dim dblPV As Double
' don't allow backspace
  If KeyCode = Asc(vbBack) Then Exit Sub
' Change string to Double value (without percent sign)
  dblPV = CDbl(Replace(Me.tbPV.Text, "%", ""))
' Show the formatted result
  Me.tbPV.Text = Format(dblPV, "0.00") & "%"
```

End Sub

**Further Remark** Naming a text box 'PV' only doesn' t seem to be state of the art. Adding a prefix - e.g. 'tb' or 'txt'- to all your **t**ext **b**oxes gives a hint to to control's original type and could give your code a comprehensible structure.

There are number of naming conventions and divergent opinions, but just to give you an impression have a look at
[Hungarian in VBA okay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572946/hungarian-in-vba-okay) or search within the Stack Overflow's "naming-conventions" tag.

Best Regards