# using classes to work with multiple ranges in excel vba

Tags: class, excel, vba

There are a couple of very good ansewers on the mechanics of using smple classes in VBA: [When to use a Class in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118863/when-to-use-a-class-in-vba) and [What are the benefits of using Classes in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161666/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-classes-in-vba)

As someone relativley new to OOP and classes, it's hard to know how to implement them, or what is even really possible.

For example, I have to deal with large ranges in multiple sheets and I need to get at many different subsets of the data.  "agents who does x" and "clients who have y"...etc.   Here's a sub i put together to get at the number of agents who have more than 2 clients:

```
Sub agent_subset(output_sheet As String, _
                                    Input_sheet_name As String, _
                                    email_col As Integer, _
                                    vendor_count_col As Integer, _
                                    client_count_col As Integer, _
                                    modified_col As Integer, _
                                    num_of_clients As Integer)
'  get a list of all agents with 2 or more clients and put them into a sheet

    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True

    Dim sheet_rows As Long
    sheet_rows = Worksheets(Input_sheet_name).Cells(rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim email_range As Range ' range of agent emails
    Dim client_count_range As Range ' range of client count
    Dim vendor_count_range As Range ' range of vendor count
    Dim modified_range As Range ' range of modified at

    With Worksheets(Input_sheet_name)
        Set email_range = .Range(.Cells(2, email_col), .Cells(sheet_rows, email_col))
        Set client_count_range = .Range(.Cells(2, client_count_col), .Cells(sheet_rows, client_count_col))
        Set vendor_count_range = .Range(.Cells(2, vendor_count_col), .Cells(sheet_rows, vendor_count_col))
        Set modified_range = .Range(.Cells(2, modified_col), .Cells(sheet_rows, modified_col))
    End With

    Dim n As Long
    Dim counter As Long
    counter = 0

    Dim modified_array() As String

    For n = 2 To sheet_rows
        If client_count_range(n, 1).Value > num_of_clients Then
            counter = counter + 1
            Worksheets(output_sheet).Cells(counter + 1, 1).Value = email_range(n, 1).Value
            Worksheets(output_sheet).Cells(counter + 1, 2).Value = client_count_range(n, 1).Value
            Worksheets(output_sheet).Cells(counter + 1, 3).Value = vendor_count_range(n, 1).Value
                modified_array() = Split(modified_range(n, 1).Value, "T")
            Worksheets(output_sheet).Cells(counter + 1, 4).Value = modified_array(0)
        End If

         Application.StatusBar = "Loop status: " & n & "of " & sheet_rows

    Next n

Worksheets(output_sheet).Cells(counter + 3, 1).Value = "Last run was " & Now()

Application.StatusBar = False

End Sub
```

It works great, but now I want to get a an even smaller subset of agents and clients based on other criteria.  So, I'm going to write a similar function, manipulating similar data.  My gut tells me using classes will make my life easier, but I don't know how to chop up the tasks.

Should there be an Agent class that has all the info about agents?  and/or a client class?  Or, should the classes be for looking at entire ranges or sheets?

I'm not looking for specific code, but a methodology on how to break things down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have to deal with large ranges in multiple sheets

If you think in terms of computers, you're code will be very functional. Those ranges represent something real (an agent, a customer, an invoice, a transaction), so think in those terms.

I would have an Agent class that held all the properties of an agent. I would have an Agents collection class that held all my Agent classes. Then, in my Agents class, I would have Filter methods that return subsets of the Agents class.

Here's an example: I have customers. Customers can be Active or not. Customers also have a template that I use when I email them certain information. When I want to email active customers who use the Table1 template, it looks like this

```
Set clsCustomersToEmail = clsCustomers.FilterOnActive(True).FilterOnTemplate("Table1")
For Each clsCustomer in clsCustomersToEmail
    'Do stuff
Next clsCustomer`
```

In my CCustomers collection class, I have a couple of properties that return a CCustomers class with few customers than the big CCustomers class (called clsCustomers)

```
Public Property Get FilterOnActive() As CCustomers

    Dim clsReturn As CCustomers
    Dim clsCustomer As CCustomer

    Set clsReturn = New CCustomers

    For Each clsCustomer In Me
        If clsCustomer.Active Then
            clsReturn.Add clsCustomer
        End If
    Next clsCustomer

    Set FilterOnActive = clsReturn

End Property
Public Property Get FilterOnTemplate(ByVal sTemplate As String) As CCustomers

    Dim clsReturn As CCustomers
    Dim clsCustomer As CCustomer

    Set clsReturn = New CCustomers

    For Each clsCustomer In Me
        If clsCustomer.Template.TemplateName = sTemplate Then
            clsReturn.Add clsCustomer
        End If
    Next clsCustomer

    Set FilterOnTemplate = clsReturn

End Property
```

When I want to do stuff like write a bunch of customer data to a range, I make a property that returns an array, and write the array to the range.

```
Set clsCustomersPastDue = clsCustomers.FilterOnActive(True).FilterOnPastDue(True)
vaWrite = clsCsutomerPastDue.AgingReport
rCell.Resize(UBound(vaWrite,1),UBound(vaWrite,2)).Value = vaWrite
```

I tend to think of what physical things am I coding. They don't have to be tangible things, but if you can take it back to something that's tangible, that can be helpful.

A transaction is a thing. But if that transaction is an invoice, now determine the properties of that object become easy. For one, you can just look at a paper invoice and see what the properties are.

The next level is relationships. Every Agent class has customers. So your Agent object should have a Customers property that returns a CCustomers class. Or if it's not structured that tightly in real life, maybe your CCustomers class has a FilterOnAgent property that returns the subset of customers you're looking for.

Comment: This is excellent!  Very helpful!  Among other things, I wasn't sure if a collection of class objects made sense, i.e. having an agent class than is then rolled up into a collection.  Thanks very much!